# PHP image proccessing crop reduce quality

Tags: php, image

I'm using PHP library from here : [Simple Image](https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage)

I'm trying to crop a 700kb image. Let say, i crop 90% of the image, the size of the result of the crop should be :

700kb - (700kb * 10%)

right ?, is the math correct ?,

Because I've tried to crop it, and the result is around 400kb. it cut almost half.

Why ?

note : I've set the quality into 80

Comment: The math is not correct as you're using a file-format that involves compression. The math would be correct for the binary memory size of the image in itself, but storing the image to disk gives you a different size. That has nothing to do with the library you link, just with memory and file formats.

Comment: @hakre aaah !, i see